# Selecting all courses + number of teachers

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

```
table: courses

course_id | slug
-------------------
1         | math
2         | science
3         | english

table: users

user_id | username
------------------
1       | john
2       | steve

table user_courses

user_course_id | user_id | course_id
------------------------------------
1              | 1       | 1
2              | 1       | 3
3              | 2       | 3
```

As you can see, the course math has only 1 teacher (john), but the course english has 2 teachers (john and steve).

I want to select all the courses from the table courses combined with the number of teachers for each course. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **the course math has only 1 teacher (john), but the course english has 2 teachers ** , is it teacher or user clear it.

Comment: teacher and user are the same... the users are 'teachers'.

Comment: You need to learn SQL.  This appears to be a beginner's homework problem.  You need two JOINs.

Comment: this question has zero indication of being **[tag:php]** related, so please remove the `php` tag.

Comment: no homework, I'm making a website to find local tutors. I think it's with a left join on the table user_courses but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT Course.slug, Count(Users.user_id) as UserCount FROM Course 
    INNER JOIN User_Course ON User_Course.course_id = Course.course_id 
    INNER JOIN Users ON Users.user_id = User_Course.course_id
    GROUP BY Course.course_id;
```

I would also have changed the logic of your user_course and used a composit primary key instead.

```
CREATE TABLE User_Course (
    user_id INT NOT NULL, 
    course_id INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, course_id),
    CONSTRAINT user_course_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id), 
    CONSTRAINT user_course_course FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES Course(course_id)
);
```

Here: [SQLFiddel](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2db1fb/1)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should post your desired result, or we can not give what you really want. Like @duffymo said, you need two `JOIN`'s, here is a solution(or a try):

```
select
   c.*,
   coalesce(count(u.user_id), 0) as teacher_cnt
from courses c
left join user_courses uc
on c.course_id = uc.course_id
left join users u
on u.user_id = uc.user_id
group by c.course_id
```

[**SqlFiddle Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24f9b/5)